# Express JS API getting stuck and CPU usage reach to 100% when reading OG tags

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

I have an API written using Nodejs and Express. I'm using an NPM package call **open-graph-scraper** (https://www.npmjs.com/package/open-graph-scraper) as a service read and response the OG tags of the URLs. When I send a request with this URL the CPU usage getting reach to the 100% and the API getting stucked until stop the server.

There is a timeout feature already provided in this NPM package but seems like the feature not working properly. It will return timeout error randomly. For some attempts, it doesn't send a timeout response at all. Also, even if I implement the timeout feature, It doesn't affect to the CPU issue.

```
import ogs = require('open-graph-scraper');

public scrapeData(req: Request, res: Response): void {
        const main = new MainController();
        try {
            const targetUrl = req.body.url || null;
            const options = { url: targetUrl, timeout: 5000, onlyGetOpenGraphInfo: true };

            ogs(options, (error: any, results: any) => {
                // This returns true or false. True if there was a error. The error it self is inside the results object.
                if (error === true) {
                    main.sendResponse(res, ResponseMessage.DATA_NOT_FOUND, results, false, ResponseCode.DATA_NOT_FOUND);
                } else {
                    if (results.data) {
                        main.sendResponse(res, ResponseMessage.DATA_FOUND, results, false, ResponseCode.DATA_NOT_FOUND);
                    } else {
                        main.sendResponse(res, ResponseMessage.DATA_NOT_FOUND, [], false, ResponseCode.DATA_NOT_FOUND);
                    }
                }
            });

        } catch (ex) {
            logger.error(ex);
            main.sendResponse(res, ResponseMessage.EXCEPTION, ex, false, ResponseCode.EXCEPTION);
        }
    }
```

This is the request URL that hangs the CPU http:// bit.ly/2YdwvgN

Comment: What does `main.sendResponse()` do?  Can we see that code?

Comment: @jfriend00 That is only to send a response back.
`public sendResponse(
    res: Response,
    message: string,
    data: any,
    success: boolean,
    code: number
  ): object {
    return res.status(code).send({
      code,
      data,
      message,
      success
    });
  }`

Comment: Are you sure that `if (error === true)` is a correct way to check for an error.  That would be unusual.  Usually, `error` would be the actual error, not just a boolean.

Comment: @jfriend00 It should be, In their documentation, they have clearly mentioned that https://www.npmjs.com/package/open-graph-scraper

Comment: OK, that's a bad way to do it, but I guess that's how they do it.

Comment: What does "API gets stuck" mean in your question?  What exactly do you observe?

Comment: @sameera danthanarayana can you just print result in console log and see how much time its taking.

Comment: @jfriend00 When I send a request to this service with this URL (http:// bit.ly/2YdwvgN)  the CPU usage keeps rotating 99.7% and 100% until I stop the API manually. Within this period API doesn't response to other service calls as well. 
For monitoring purposes, I'm using 'top' command

Comment: That sounds like `ogs()` just hogging the CPU doing whatever it does.  Perhaps in an infinite loop, I odn't know.  Nothing else in the code you show would do that.

Comment: @jfriend00, Definitely, Whatever the things which makes the CPU hopping, It should be there inside the **open-graph-scraper** NPM package.
What I wanted to know is some way to control that from my side instead of changing it in the external package?

Comment: All you can control is the options you pass it.  You'd have to study and maybe instrument its code to see where it goes haywire before you can understand how that might be fixed either by changing what you pass it or by fixing the code in the library itself.